# Problema con las imagenes en media al subir a heroku con Django

Tags: python, django

Hice mi portfolio y lo subi a heroku. Cuando estaba en desarrollo las imagenes de los proyectos se veian bien, pero al subirlo a heroku no se ven. Las imagenes que estan en static si se ven bien, solo las de media.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: me puedes compartir la forma de como usaste el servico de s3 bucket , tengo el mismo problema con heroku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuve que usar el servicio S3 Bucket de AWS.

Answer (score 1):

La carpeta media se usa para los archivos que cargan los usuarios en tu aplicación. El problema es que Heroku cada 30 minutos vuelve a su estado original eliminando todos los archivos que hayan podido subir los usuarios.

### Solución

Utiliza una base de datos para memorizar esos archivos.

Comment: Y como hago para que las imagenes se guarden en la db?

Comment: Hay varias maneras, puedes usar [base64](https://programacion.net/articulo/codificar_y_decodificar_en_base64_con_python_1385) para convertir los archivos en una stringa o puedes usar bases de datos como la de [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/es/s3/). En este [repositorio](https://github.com/Ariel-MN/Tkinter_base64_Images) de GitHub tengo un ejemplo de como usar base64.

Comment: Ya lo solucione, use el s3 bucket de aws